# ScrollView causes to move button from bottom up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have couple textfields and button a the bottom inside LinearLayout and it looks ok. I want to add around ScrollView so when keyboard shows that I can scroll. When I add ScrollView my button from bottom and shows up on center screen. (If there is no ScrollView it is a the bottom of screen, where it should be). What to change to make this works and button be inside scroll but on the bottom of screen.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="269px"
            android:layout_height="161px"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/show" />

        <com.example.widgets.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_message"
            style="@style/paragraph"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="80px"
            android:text="@string/pin/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="150px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.example.widgets.CustomTextView
                style="@style/caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/pin_enter" />

            <com.example.widgets.CustomEditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_code"
                style="@style/pin"
                android:layout_width="310px"
                android:layout_height="110px"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_edit_text"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            style="@style/button"
            android:layout_width="625px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/login" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically can not.

`ScrollView`'s child is per definition measured as `wrap_content`. That's the reason, why your inner `View`s is shrinked to the minimum size fitting the content.

Move the `Button`s out of the `ScrollView` (on the same level of hierarchy), if you want to have them fixed on the bottom.